# CSS file causing error in react/webpack configuration

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have a fullstack project, which is made with Django-REST and React as the frontend.

Everytime i try to load a css file into my react application i get an error

```
import './Dashboard.css'
```

export default class Dashboard extends Component {

```
render() {
...
```

Dashboard.css

```
body {
margin:0;
}
```

[image: Picture of the error]
here is my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
module: {
       rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

what is weird to me is that, inline css, works just fine, it's only when i try to load an external sheet, that i get issues. Does anybody know what may be the cause of the problem?

Comment: And when you leave the .css file empty, the error is still there?

Comment: As mentioned in the error, you likely need to use a CSS loader such as [this one](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader).

Comment: @josemartindev no only when there is CSS rules applied

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a css-loader. Update **`webpack.config.js`** to this:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

And install the loader:

```
npm install --save-dev css-loader
```

It should build properly now. You can read more in the Webpack [**docs**](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/)

Comment: should i add this to the existing rules?

Comment: or should i just add an existing module?

Comment: @baileyhaldwin I already added it for you. You can just copy paste my answer and replace what you have in your webpack.config.js

Comment: absolutely, I had to wait 4 minutes to accept the answer.

Comment: @baileyhaldwin woah, didn't realize I was that quick :D